# F# How to distribute an item across every element in a list using recursion

Tags: f#

I am trying to distribute a single item across every element in a list. For example, if I had a list [1,2,3] and an item "DOG". I would like to get the result [("DOG", 1); ("DOG", 2); ("DOG", 3)].
I am trying to use a match expression to complete this, but I am not sure how to start. I currently have:

```
let rec con (x: 'a) (l: 'b list) =
        match l with 
        | [] -> []
```

Answer (score 2):

A way to transform every item of a list in some way is the `List.map` function. It takes two parameters: a function for transforming every item and the list itself.

```
let l = [1; 2; 3]
let dogs = List.map (fun x -> ("DOG", x)) l
```

Answer (score 1):

Fyodor's answer is the best way to do this, but if you want a recursive solution with pattern matching, it would look like this:

```ml
let rec con (x: 'a) (l: 'b list) =
    match l with 
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t -> (x, h) :: (con x t)
```

Or, more succinctly:

```ml
let rec con x = function
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t -> (x, h) :: (con x t)
```

Test code:

```ml
con "DOG" [1; 2; 3]
    |> printfn "%A"   // [DOG,1; DOG,2; DOG,3]
```